# Convert react function component to react class component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-class-based-component

I am learning react and need some help from you guys.
I wants need to convert my react hook function to react class component.

React Hook ;

```
const Card = () => {
const [model, setModel] = useState(false);
const [tempData, setTempdata] = useState([]);
const getData = (img, title, desc, votes, comments, views) => {
    let tempData = [img, title, desc, votes, comments, views];
    setTempdata(item => [1, ...tempData]);
    return setModel(true);
}
return(
    <>
        <section className='py-4 py-lg-5 container'>
            <div className='row justify-content-center align-item-center'>
                {data.cardData.map((item, index) => {
                    return(
                        <div className='col-11 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mx-0 mb-4' key={index} onClick={() => getData(item.imgSrc, item.title, item.desc, item.votes, item.comments, item.views)}>
                            <div className="card p-0 over-flow-hidden h-100 shadow bg-transparent">
                                <img className="card-img-top" src={item.imgSrc} alt=""></img>
                                <div className="card-body bg-dark">
                                    <small className="text-white">{item.title}</small>
                                    <small className="text-muted card-detail">
                                        <small className='text-muted'><FaArrowUp className='card_icons'/>{item.votes}</small>
                                        <small className='text-muted'><FaRegCommentAlt className='card_icons card_icon2' />{item.comments}</small>
                                        <small className='text-muted'><FaRegEye className='card_icons card_icon3' />{item.views}</small>
                                    </small>
                                </div>          
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
                
            </div>
        </section>
        {
            model === true ? <Model img={tempData[1]} title={tempData[2]} desc={tempData[3]} votes={tempData[4]} comments={tempData[5]} views={tempData[5]} hide={() => setModel(false)} />: ''
        }
    </>
)
```

}

I have tried but it didn't work. Please help me to do this.

Comment: Maybe you mean: you want to convert from functional component into class component.

Comment: @yohanes Yes, exactly I need this.

Answer (score 0):

For simple components like this, where you just need to maintain state and map over some data is really easy.

Basically, instead of defining each state variable using a seperate useState, define all of then inside this.state. This can be inside the constructor of the class or as a member

**Defining state inside the constructor**

```
class Card extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      /* define your state inside this*/
      model: props.model,
    };
  }
}
```

**Defining state as a member of class**

```
class Card extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    model: false,
  }
}
```

If the initial value inside state depends on the your initial props, use the constructor method.
If the initial value inside state is always going to be the same, use either approach.

To update the state, you need to use the this.setState method
And the rest of jsx is pretty much the same.

Here is what your component would finally look like

```
import React from 'react';

class Card extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      model: false,
      tempData: [],
    };
  }

  getData = (/* your method parameters here */) => {
    const tempData = [/* define the tempData here */];
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      tempData: [1, ...tempData], // dont understand what 1 does here
      model: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        ...your jsx here
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```